# Why Android Studio with Retrofit or Volley sends all requests as GET?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-volley

I am programming android applications with retrofit and volley to consume APIs, the endpoints handle different methods but when I program them all are sent with the GET method.

I am debugging with Android Studio and I also generate the APKs, I test them on different devices but the result is the same.

Comment: No. A POST is a POST. A GET is a GET.

Comment: please add some content to your question.

Comment: add piece of code. we can send POST or GET request as per our requirement.

Comment: no it not what ever request you want to send you will able to send like(Request.method.Get or Post).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.